# Loading the pre-trained model of torch and sentence_transformers when running in a docker container failing

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, pytorch, sentence-transformers

I am getting below error while loading the pre-trained model of torch and `sentence_transformers("distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens")` when trying to run in a docker container.

```
Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
 Unable to load celery application.
 While trying to load the module app.celery the following error occurred:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 53, in convert
     return find_app(value)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 384, in find_app
     sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
     module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 100, in import_from_cwd
     return imp(module, package=package)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/code/app.py", line 997, in <module>
     load_model()
   File "/code/app.py", line 255, in load_model
     embedder = SentenceTransformer('distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py", line 48, in __init__
     os.makedirs(model_path, exist_ok=True)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
   [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
     mkdir(name, mode)
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/nonexistent'
```

Here it is saying permission denied error while creating the folder. But I have tried providing `USER root` in the `Dockerfile`. Stuck with this issue for long time. Please anyone help me here.

*Updated:*
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-slim

WORKDIR /code

ENV ENVIRONMENT='LOCAL'
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo netcat apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev  build-essential python3-pip

COPY ./requirements_local.txt /code/requirements_local.txt
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements_local.txt

EXPOSE 8000
COPY . /code/

CMD [ "gunicorn", "app:app", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000","--timeout","7200"]
```

*Docker-compose*:

```
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.prod
    hostname: flaskapp
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    links:
      - redis
      - celery
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - data:/code
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ubuntu/models
        target: /mnt/models
```

Comment: Can you add the Dockerfile? How do you launch the container? ( please provide command args or compose file)

Comment: Hi @anemyte, I just have added the Dockerfile. I am launching using docker-compose on AWS EC2.

Comment: Seems like it's `gunicorn` workers running that script of yours (which creates the directory). They must not run under root for security reasons but for a test you can run both the container and gunicorn workers as root to check the theory.

Comment: How to run gunicorn as root in Dockerfile. I tried using CMD [ "sudo","gunicorn", "app:app", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000","--timeout","7200"]. But didn't work out.

Comment: Changing Dockerfile is too slow to test - better change `docker-compose.yml`. Add `command: [ "gunicorn", "app:app", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000","-u","0","--timeout","7200"]` and `user: root` to it.

Comment: I got it working by my own. Actually, I'm also using celery and redis. Here celery is actually causing the issue. It is also trying to load all the models and failing to create correct directories for sentence_transformers in docker for user:nobody. I tested the app by removing celery and celery-beat. And now it is working perfectly fine. But I could not make it working using them. If you know any solution, please let me know too. Btw, I will try with your approach also and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar neither with your application nor with some libs that you use and thus it is hard for me to give you clear instructions. But the general idea is that you run the app as any user but root. If your app requires some directories - make 'em in Dockerfile and don't forget to assign right ownership and permissions.

Answer (score 5):

sentence-transformers downloads and stores model in ~/.cache directory (or whatever the cache_folder evaluates to be in - https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/a13a4ec98b8fdda83855aca7992ea793444a207f/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L63). For you this looks like the /nonexistant directory. The permission denied error suggests you do not have permission to access that directory (to create cache folder).

You can modify the Dockerfile to create this directory and make it accessible to any user that needs to access this:-

```
RUN mkdir ~/.cache
RUN chmod -R 777 ~/.cache # don't do this in production - modify command to give permission to users who require it.
```

Or you could try downloading the model in the Dockerfile itself -

```
RUN python -c 'from sentence-transformers import SentenceTransformer; embedder = SentenceTransformer("distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens")'
```

Comment: In case anyone wants to copy the run line the sentence transformers lib has an underscore note a dash so it would be 

`RUN python -c 'from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer; embedder = SentenceTransformer("distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens")'` Thanks so much great answer

Comment: Literally I can't explain how many things I've tried to get the model prebaked into a docker image, that run line has been the only thing to work straight away ♥️♥️

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, am using **bert-base-NER**

`RUN python3 -c 'from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification; tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER"); model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")'`